# XMLHttpRequest launches multiple times without initiating the onreadystatechange function

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, userscripts

The userscript in question: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/130532

After the site it's been made for has been updated to HTML5, I had to update the script. However, it's got a really big problem now. When I launch the script's main function that contains the XMLHttpRequest, it simply spams the console with these requests until the browser simply crashes.

Now, I looked around in both StackOverflow and in Google for anything that could help me, but there's nothing.

If you proceed to try the script, be careful, because it crashes the browser. Or at least, it does for me in FF 11.00

Code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Where my thread at
// @include        *//boards.4chan.org/*/res/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    "use strict";
    var board = document.location.href.match(/https?:\/\/boards\.4chan\.org\/[\w]+/i), threadNo = location.pathname.match(/\/res\/([\d]+)/i), main = document.getElementsByName("delform")[0], is404 = 0, ttt = null, b, c, num, timer, html, i, l, no, found, xhr1, xhr2, cstatus, ui, pg;

    function lookup(resp) {
        html = resp.match(/<div class="postContainer opContainer".*?<\/div>[^<]*?<\/div>/gi);
        if (html) {
            l = html.length;
            for (i = 0; i < l; i += i) {
                no = html[i].match(/<a href="res\/([\d]+)"/i)[1];
                if (threadNo[1] === no) {
                    document.getElementById('page').innerHTML = pg;
                    cstatus.innerHTML = "Status:&nbsp;Done";
                    found = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function doIndex(pg) {
        b = document.getElementById('shouldi');
        if (!is404 && b.checked === true) {
            cstatus.innerHTML = "Status:&nbsp;Searching";
            c = document.getElementById('timerbox');
            num = parseInt(c.value, 10);
            if (num > 600) { timer = 600; }
            if (num < 30) { timer = 30; }
            if (isNaN(num)) {
                timer = 60;
                alert("Value entered is not a valid number! Defaulting to 60");
                c.value = "60";
            }
            if (!timer) { timer = num; }
            xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr1.open("GET", board[0] + (0 === pg ? "" : "/" + pg), true);
            xhr1.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            xhr1.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr1.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr1.status === 200) {
                        lookup(xhr1.responseText);
                    }
                }
                if (found) {
                    ttt = setTimeout(function () {
                        doIndex(0);
                    }, timer * 1000);
                } else {
                    if (pg < 15) {
                        doIndex(pg + 1);
                    } else {
                        cstatus.innerHTML = "Status:&nbsp;Really 404?";
                        xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr2.open("GET", board[0] + threadNo[0], true);
                        xhr2.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                        xhr2.onreadystatechange = function () {
                            if (xhr2.readyState === 4) {
                                if (xhr2.status === 404) {
                                    cstatus.parentNode.removeChild(cstatus);
                                    document.getElementById('page').innerHTML = "404'd";
                                    is404 = 1;
                                } else {
                                    cstatus.innerHTML = "Status:&nbsp;Still alive";
                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                        doIndex(0);
                                    }, 1000);
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        xhr2.send(null);
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr1.send(null);
        }
    }

    ui = document.createElement('center');
    ui.innerHTML = '<table border="0" style="width: 100%"><tbody><tr><td style="width: 33%;text-align: right;">Timer(600-30s):&nbsp;<input type="text" value="30" maxlength="3" size="3" id="timerbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 33%">&nbsp;<center><font size="20" color="red" id="page">&nbsp;</font></center>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 33%;text-align:left;">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="checkcheck"><label for="shouldi">Checking</label><input type="checkbox" id="shouldi" /></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="checkstatus">Status:&nbsp;</span></td></tr></tbody></table>';
    main.parentNode.insertBefore(ui, main);
    cstatus = document.getElementById('checkstatus');
    cstatus.innerHTML = "Status:&nbsp;Ready";
    document.getElementById('checkcheck').addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (ttt !== null) {
            clearTimeout(ttt);
            ttt = null;
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            doIndex(0);
        }, 500);
    }, false);
}());
```

Comment: @BrockAdams The OP is the author of that script (see Gravatar). The code has to be included in the question though, because it's possible to delete the user script, leaving this question useless to future visitors.

Comment: @RobW, Good eye (Or else the OP hacked poor KittyAwesome's account ;) ).  You're right that the code should be included, but this question still seems unlikely to help any but the OP.

Comment: I don't plan on deleting this userscript ever, so don't worry. Besides, userscripts.org has a version history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using several variables **without declaring** these **locally**:

```
var ..., found, xhr1, xhr2, cstatus, ui, pg;
...
function doIndex(pg) {
    ...
        xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
     // ^^^^ No var !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        ...
        xhr1.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr1.readyState === 4) { ... }
            if (found) {
                ...
            } else {
                if (pg < 15) {
                    doIndex(pg + 1); // <-- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                } else { ...
                    xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    ...
                    xhr2.onreadystatechange = function() { ... };
                    xhr2.send(null);
                }
            }
        };
        xhr1.send(null);
    }
}  ...
doIndex(0); // Initiate the doom
```

First, you assign a new XHR instance to a non-local `xhr1` variable.
Then, you add a `readystatechange` event handler, in which the following happens:

1. Initially, `readyState` is not four, so `found` is false. Since `pg` starts at 0, `doIndex(pg + 1)` is called. Now, **`xhr1` gets overwritten by a new XHR instance**.
2. This continues, until `pg` reaches 15. Then, `pg < 15` is false, and the horror starts:

   - `xhr1.onreadystatechange` fires multiple time during the request. `pg < 15` is false, so the `else` block is evaluated, in which you launch several new XHR (`xhr2`) requests...
   - **All of the previous readystatechange events are still fired, because the requests haven't finished yet. In every event handler, you're comparing the value of `xhr1.readyState`, which refers to the state of the *last* created `xhr1` request**.
     So, you're calling `doIndex(pg+1)` over and over again, which, once `pg` has reached 15, creates new XHR (`xhr2`) instances.

To fix the problem, declare the variables in the function, and wrap the whole `onreadystatechange` block in `if (xhr1.readyState == 4)` (or use [`onload`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#event-xhr-load) instead of `onreadystatechange`).

```
function dIndex(pg) {
    var xhr1, xhr2;
    ...
    xhr1.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr1.readyState === 4) {
           /* ... */
        }
    };
    ...
```

Comment: Well, I have  played around with the things you said, but somehow neither of them worked as expected. I finally gave up and went back to an earlier version and updated it. It also doesn't work as it should now, because when I tick the checkbox it fires the XMLHttpRequest twice on the first board page. If you have any idea, feel free to write in the script's discussion page.

Answer (score 0):

This helped based on answers:

```
                    let signupRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    let url = "signup/" + inputMobile.value;
                    signupRequest.open("GET", url, true);
                    signupRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    signupRequest.send();

                    signupRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (signupRequest.readyState === 4) {
                            hideLoading();
                            if (signupRequest.status === 200) {
                                console.log("OK: " + status + " --- " + signupRequest.response);
                            } else {
                                console.log("NOK: " + status + " --- " + signupRequest.response);
                            }
                        }
                    };
```