# Why does I get "Cannot read property 'obj2' of undefined" on one but not the on the other one?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

Hi im trying to make a script where i can get more info of an object by pressing one button but i have had some problems so far. The code works fine on the fist "Drue" when i hit "mer info" but if i try to press the "Eple" or one of the other one i get the error "Cannot read property 'objX' of undefined" where X is the name of the array in the php

This is just the code for the two first objects "Drue" and "Eple"

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.onreadystatechange = function () {              
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        var response = request.responseText;
        var mink = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        text.innerHTML = mink[0].obj1;
        epletext.innerHTML = mink[1].obj1;
        banantext.innerHTML = mink[2].obj1;
        orangetext.innerHTML = mink[3].obj1;
    } else {
        text.innerHTML = "pissing..."; 
        epletext.innerHTML = "pissing..."; 
        banantext.innerHTML = "pissing..."; 
        orangetext.innerHTML = "pissing..."; 
    }
}
request.open("GET", "info.php", true);
request.send();

btn.onclick = function (){
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {              
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            if (drue == 0) {
                var response = request.responseText;
                var mink = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                text.innerHTML = mink[0].obj2;
                drue = 1;
            } else {
                var response = request.responseText;
                var mink = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                text.innerHTML = mink[0].obj1;
                drue = 0;
            }                   
        } else {
            text.innerHTML = "pissing..."; 
        }
    }
    request.open("GET", "info.php", true);
    request.send();
}

eple.onclick = function (){
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            if (eplenr == 0) {
                var response = request.responseText;
                var mink = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                epletext.innerHTML = mink[1].obj2;
                eplenr = 1;
            } else {
                var response = request.responseText;
                var mink = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                epletext.innerHTML = mink[1].obj1;
                eplenr = 0;
            }

        } else {
            epletext.innerHTML = "pissing..."; 
        }
    }
    request.open("GET", "info.json", true);
    request.send();
}
```

And this is the php code i have used

```
<?php
$shop = array( 
            array( "obj1" => "en fin kladd druer", 
                   "obj2" => "en nydelig kladd med ferske druer hentet fjellene i frankrike, gravd ned ved røttene til palmene i Miama og fryst i isen på Grønnland for å gi den perfekte smaken de har",
                ),
            array( "obj1" => "et grønnt og fint eple", 
                   "obj2" => "et fantastisk eple hentet fra hagen til Gjermung",
                ),
            array( "obj1" => "en pakke er på 4 bananer", 
                   "obj2" => "Bananene er håndplukket av slaveaper i skogene i Atlantis",
                ),
            array( "obj1" => "store appelsiner", 
                   "obj2" => "disse appelsiene er det ikke noe spessielt med, de er helt vanlige, noen av dem har litt mugg på seg",
                )
);


header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($shop);
?>
```

Thanks for taking a look at it

Comment: Why are you binding an `onreadystatechange` handler inside a `click` handler?

Comment: can i have it outside the `click` handler?

Comment: I didn't notice that you were resending the AJAX request as well, I needed to scroll down. However, it's not a good idea to reuse the same XHR object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502244/reuse-xmlhttprequest-object-or-create-a-new-one

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log(mink)` in the `eple` handler.

Comment: where in the `eple` handler do you want me to put it?

Comment: After `mink=JSON.parse(request.responseText)`. BTW, why do you assign `response`, but not use it?

Comment: I got `Object {obj1: Object, eple1: Object, banan1: Object, orange1: Object} `. I dont kbow why I use `response` it was somthin my teatcher told me to do

Comment: You got a single object, not an array of 4 objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access `mink[0].obj2` when `mink[0]` doesn't exist. You could easily check for this

```
if (mink) text.innerHtml = mink[0].obj;
```

Comment: I can acsess the `mink[0].obj2` but not `mink[1].obj2` an so on. `mink[0].obj2` is the text "en nydelig kladd med ferske druer hentet fjellene i frankrike, gravd ned ved røttene til palmene i Miama og fryst i isen på Grønnland for å gi den perfekte smaken de har"

Comment: What does a console log of `mink` look like?

Comment: if i console.log mink i get 4 objects

Comment: where do you want me to put the line of code you put in your answer?