# Javascript make a post request and receive multiple responses

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I receive multiple response from the server?
The server sends to the client 3 different responses. Unfortunately my code catches only the first(I Think) one.

The client (html page) make a post request and the server replies to the client 3 different times. How can I catch all the 3 response?

This is the index.html page with the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    console.log('begin');
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();



    var data={
        'query'        : "test"
    }


    data=JSON.stringify(data);


    http.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080", true);

    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log('onreadystatechange');
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            console.log(http.responseText);
        }
        else {
            console.log('readyState=' + http.readyState + ', status: ' + http.status);
        }
    }

    console.log('sending...')
    http.send(data);
    console.log('end');

</script>
```

In NODE JS I can catch all the responses in this way... is there something similar?

```
var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': data.length
    }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log("body: " + chunk);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a new instance of XMLHttpRequest for EACH request.

Comment: the client (html page) make a post request and the server replies to the client 3 different times. How can I catch all the 3 response?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The server can only respond once to a request. 1 HTTP request maps to 1 response. For 2 responses you need 2 requests, for 3 you need 3 and so on.

Comment: the server replies with a message divided in chunks

Comment: Doesn't matter how it is packaged up, HTTP does not involve more than 1 reply to a single request. If the reply from the server is divided into two parts then two requests would be needed, one for each part.

Comment: thanks but why I can catch all the 3 responses with the node js code?

Comment: Because you're making 3 requests, but I assume re-using the same XMLHttpRequest instance to do so if I understand the original question correctly (this is not a good idea - see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502244/reuse-xmlhttprequest-object-or-create-a-new-one).