# Post request with JQuery and receive multiple answers, possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know how to do a post-request with jquery and get one response, but I wonder If I can post something with AJAX and then wait for multiple responses.

The idea behind it is that I have a progressbar (which I want to animate), so I need to get the status of the execution in my background code, which I called with AJAX.

Is this possible? I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30139947/javascript-make-a-post-request-and-receive-multiple-responses). But it didn't help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you having an issue with just making several AJAX requests and handling the responses in their callbacks?

Comment: @AndrewCheong: I have one script in the background, which I call with AJAX...not many.

Comment: Right, but why not make more than one AJAX call? _e.g._ dispatch an AJAX call every 5 seconds? There's nothing that says that script can't be called more than once.

Comment: @AndrewCheong The thing is, I have a script in my background which does some things, and I    can't / don't want   to split this in several scripts. I want to call this script with AJAX once, and receive multiple responses which tell me which steps of the script were executed and which still need to be executed, so that I can show a progressbar.

Comment: It looks like you didn't really understand the http protocol. One request triggers one response, unless you keep the socket open and fragment the response into chunks (unlikely you will want to do this). The other approach would be to use websockets or similar to open a tcp connection, in order to push status updates. I don't think you'll be able to achieve this easily with the request / response model.

Comment: @Martin: Yeah I don't want to use tcp/ip. How could I keep the socket open?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to identify the status for ajax when this execute into your web page. Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//in your DOM, CALL YOUR FUNCTION

    loading();

    //set an interval to stop de function if the ajax is ready and all elements are ready
    $load = {
        setInterval(function() {
            loading();
        }, 1000); //each one second this Interval was checked if the page is complety ready
    }

    function loading() {

        var x = document.readyState;
        switch (x) {
            case 'loading';
                //show, hide something or animate an toolbar before of 50%
            break;

            case 'interactive';
                 //show, hide something or animate an toolbar before of 70%
            break;

            case 'complete';
                //show, hide something
                //we clean the interval to sstop if is compete and show the toolbar in 100%
                clearInterval($load);
            break;
        }

    }

</script>
```

You can learn more about Ready State property here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_readystate.asp